# PDF files larger than 100 MB failing to download

Tags: php

I have one confusion here, what if memory_limit is not mentioned in PHP.INI file of PHP 8.1 then what will be limit of memory_limit in this case?

Recently we migrated from PHP 7.3 to PHP 8.1 and looks like memory_limit was not mentioned in PHP.INI file of PHP 7.3 as well

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)? It says it defaults to 128M.

Comment: You might try a little script with `<?php phpinfo();` in it for insight. Also, I've just looked up any number of old versions, and `memory_limit` is there in `php.ini` for them all. Where are you looking at, and what platform?

Comment: In PHP.ini , memory_limit was commented in PHP.INI so got confused. It was prod environement so could not print phpinfo to check. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after comparing the PHP.INI files of verison 7.3 and 8.1.

We have an application which provides download options to large PDF files but after migrating to PHP 8.1, PDF files larger than 100 MB were failing to download.

Here culprit was param "output_buffering"

Made below changes and now downloads are fine

`output_buffering = Off`

Comment: So that should have been your question. Not random musings on the causes, but the actual problem. Notice how your current answer is strikingly irrelevant to the question that has been initially asked.

Comment: Point taken, I was wondering about the cause of it